# How to get list of files in a pull request in a github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a github action that will automatically request reviewers based on the names of the files that are in the change. For example, if the diff contains a `*.sql` file, I'd like to request a review from a specific person, and likewise for other file extensions.

This action on the marketplace is what I'm starting with: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/auto-assign-action. I thought the best way to do this would be to use a conditional, something like:

```
name: 'DB Review'
on: pull_request

jobs:
  add-reviews:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: kentaro-m/auto-assign-action@v1.0.1
        if: "{{ contains(github.files, '.sql') }}"
        with:
          repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like this magical diff list exists: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context, so I was hoping for some other suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be to use the [pull_requests.paths](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) filter and create a new workflow for each of the file types when a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull-request-event-pull_request) is opened you want to handle, along with the people who can handle them.

For example:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
    paths:
    - '**.sql'

jobs:
  add-sql-reviews:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: kentaro-m/auto-assign-action@v1.0.1
        with:
          repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          configuration-path: ".github/auto_assign_sql.yml"
```

Now you create this workflow for each file pattern group you want to support and configure who the reviewers are in each of the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The [pull_requests.paths filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) is one option, but I think you'll end up with a workflow for each file pattern if you do it that way? Assuming you are going to create more of these...

You could write a custom step in the job which uses the [pull request files API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests-files), and then you might have a job for each pattern? And an auto-assign config for each job too?

If you're just looking to assign reviewers based on paths, you might consider using [GitHub's CODEOWNERS feature](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) instead of a custom workflow. Or if you're looking for more control than that but don't want to write it yourself, [PullApprove lets you create assignment rules and groups using almost any data in the GitHub API](https://www.pullapprove.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: List files in the repository
  run: |
      ls ${{ github.workspace }}
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).